# Simple Injector register multiple type of same interface with metadata

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have the following problem. I have one interface say `IFoo` and multiple implementations from it. Now, I have one web API controller, which according to some circumstances, should create a particular type of `IFoo` descendant, call it's method(s) and return result. The logic of the controller doesn't change no matter which implementation of `IFoo` I use. For this task, I need to tell the container which `IFoo` implementation to create from the controller, the problem is that, I don't know how to do that (if it's even possible with Simple Injector).

P.S. I already thought about `RegisterAll`, but in this case I'm forced to create all `IFoo` descendants (and pass it to the controller) when I need only one. This is not a solution for me.

Another solution would be to create different controllers for different `IFoo` implementations and use context based injection, but this will result in duplicated code/controllers that I want to avoid.

Ideally, the solution should be something like

```
container.RegisterAllWithMetadata(IEnumerable<Type> types, IEnumerable<string> metadata)
container.GetInstance(Type type, string metadata)
```

Is it possible to achieve my goal with Simple Injector?

Comment: Your use case is described quite clearly in the documentation here: https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto.html#resolve-instances-by-key

Comment: @Steven thanks, I missed that from the docs :(. Can you post that as answer so I can mark as one :)

Comment: I'm back from holiday and ready to create an answer to your question, but what I'm wondering is, what determines which IFoo implementation should be injected? Is that a configuration value, or does it depend on some request variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry for bringing it back to life, but as it was said in the comments by Steven, your answer is in the [docs](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto.html#register-factory-delegates)

In situations where a service needs to create multiple instances of a certain dependencies, or needs to explicitly control the lifetime of such dependency, abstract factories can be used. Instead of injecting an IMyService, you should inject an IMyServiceFactory that creates new instances of IMyService:

```
// Definition
public interface IMyServiceFactory {
    IMyService CreateNew();
}

// Implementation
sealed class ServiceFactory : IMyServiceFactory {
    public IMyService CreateNew() {
        return new MyServiceImpl();
    }
}

// Registration
container.RegisterSingle<IMyServiceFactory, ServiceFactory>();

// Usage
public class MyService {
    private readonly IMyServiceFactory factory;

    public MyService(IMyServiceFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public void SomeOperation() {
        using (var service1 = this.factory.CreateNew()) {
            // use service 1
        }

        using (var service2 = this.factory.CreateNew()) {
            // use service 2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's how I ended up doing. Thanks anyway :)